# Cannot fetch data from MySQL database with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to write a program that receives data from an XBee and then uploads the data to a database. The program is written in Python. I got the XBee part right, but when I try to execute a SQL command I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
from xbee import ZigBee
import serial
import MySQLdb

PORT = 'COM4'
BAUD_RATE = 9600

# Open serial port
ser = serial.Serial(PORT, BAUD_RATE)

zb = ZigBee(ser, escaped = True)

#DATA BASE CONNECTION

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","b3")

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# execute SQL query using execute() method.
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")

# Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
data = cursor.fetchone()

print "Database version : %s " % data


def checkSistem(sistemCode):
    sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM sistema WHERE Codigo = '"+sistemCode+"'"   

    try:
        # Execute the SQL command
        cursor.execute(sql)
        # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
        results = cursor.fetchone()
        print results[0] 
    except:
        print "Error: unable to fecth data"    


while True:
    try:
        dataXBee = zb.wait_read_frame() 
        data =  dataXBee['rf_data'].decode("utf-8").split(",")
        checkSistem(data[0])


        print (data[1])

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

And when I run the program I get this:

```
Database version : 5.6.26 
Error: unable to fecth data
S1
```

Comment: i fixed it doing this db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="pass",db="b3")